# Streaming connection / long polling with HTTP Kit?

Tags: http, clojure, http-kit

I'm trying to consume an HTTP streaming connection that never closes (it's the Gnip Compliance stream).

I want to work with [HTTP Kit](http://www.http-kit.org/), but I can't get it to work. If I pass the `:stream` argument:

```
@(http/get "http://example.com/stream-connection" {:as :stream})
```

The response doesn't return until the request is closed (and it will never be completed).

Is there a way to do this?

I've tried the same thing with [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#output-coercion), no luck.

Comment: Did you check examples on http-kit website: http://www.http-kit.org/server.html#async?

Comment: No. I don't think the server is relevant to the client?

Comment: Oh, my bad - I misread your question - sorry.

Comment: No worries. There is a lot more detail for Java (/Clojure) servers than clients.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making it async via callback:

```
(http/get "http://example.com/stream-connection" {:as :stream}
              (fn [{:keys [status headers body error opts]}]
                ;; body is a java.io.InputStream
                (with-open [inp body]
                  (let [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader inp)]
                    (doseq [i (cheshire.core/parsed-seq rdr)]
                      (println i))))))
```

In my understanding the connection is hanging until it reads the whole stream (which is neverending), so you shouldn't use deref here.
Instead, you should use an asynchronous callback and iterate stream reader.